# Regarding IllegalStateExceptions, MediaPlayer, failed prepares and State codes

Tags: android, media-player, ioexception

I have been struggling quite a lot with our beloved MediaPlayer class...
Specifically I want to simply play sounds from some Files... 
I am getting two specific types of errors actually, and not continuesly but it seems like random... Sometimes 10 files are played rigth away with no errors, then the MediPlayer seems to stop accepting another File...
Ok the  first error :

```
- 05-26 15:02:00.916: ERROR/MediaPlayer(25793): error (1, -4)
- 05-26 15:02:00.916: ERROR/setupplayer(25793): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

Well for this one I have seen several solutions :
use

```
mp.setDataSource(ins.getFD()); (with ins being an inputstream to my File)
```

and/or to use

```
mp.setDataSource(ins.getFD(), 0, f.length());
```

Both unfortunately won't solve the problem, and I would simply LOVE to know what the very exhaustive error(1,-4) is... And where can I find the codes of the States of the MediaPlayer ?
Also I have tried using prepareAsync() instead of prepare() but to be honest it doesn't seem to make any difference at all..
The second error is the Exception which is thrown :

```
05-26 15:17:30.456: ERROR/playNextPlayer(27303): Error caught : java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

Which, I guess, might be related to the first error/problem ?

Comment: Playing 10 files? Are you sure you don't want to use a `SoundPool`?

Comment: no thanks, those 10 files are dynamically downloaded from the net, and they are possibly inbetween the 30 seconds and the minute, my understanding is that SoundPool is only a good option if it's for shorter preloaded game-type sounds ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `mp.setDataSource(String path)`
For example,`mp.setDataSource("sdcard/1.mp3");`

The error is coming because of incorrect path or FileDescriptor.

You should check the [State Diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) of Mediaplayer class